# Is word-wrap style safe to apply on body?

Tags: html, css

Is this safe?

```
* { word-wrap: break-word }
```

I have too many places where I have to apply this style. Could any evil come from this line? What issues I may have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, * is technically not just on the `BODY` but also `HTML` (yes, sometimes it matters).

Secondly, in isolated cases, using the wildcard can cause performance issues. I have only seen this when using something (admittedly horrible) like DHTML behaviors, but in my opinion it would be better to declare an explicit set of elements to which it applies.

Lastly, it will clutter up all your CSS viewing tools with a potentially unneeded statement.

So, no big problem, but I would suggest just listing the elements that it is actually relevant to, such as P, possibly TD, DIV, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's no evil in that. Usually I measure the CSS parameters I need and decide wich ones will belong to the document and wich ones are to be treated locally. In your case, if you find that usefull, you just need to ensure that any element that you don't want to behave like that is properly told so.

Answer (score 1):

I apply it just to the body element, like the question suggests:

```
body { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me. I can't see of any downsides and it's very rare that you want words to overflow the body.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you understand that you'll have to override that behavior when setting styles for other elements, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't do any "evil", but the common sense inside me is saying that surely it would be better to just apply it to the elements which require it?

Even if your selector does end up looking like `.this, #that, p, li.menu, .x, .yz, #something.class` :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably wouldn't be a major issue using the property. It used to be native to IE but is fully supported by the more recent versions of modern browsers. It sometimes bungles text justification in older browser versions, though.

I would advise against * and instead go with the elements that contain text (div, p, td, etc.). It will make things a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `word-wrap` on `body` alone is sufficient because all other elements will inherit it. So no need to apply with universal selector!